# Sending values from a multi picklist to an account in pardot

Tags: visual-workflow, formula, multi-select

I have a custom multi picklist field on my account object that tells us some required documentation we need from an account. We want to set up an automatic engagement that lets people know when they have documentation we need from them. For example let's say that we need their driver's license and a proof of address, we'd select those options from the picklist, then the next day they'll get an email through pardot which says something like

"hey so and so,

We're so excited to get you started with our service. We just need a few more items from you:

driver's license
proof of address

Please get those back to us and we'll get you on your way"

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.